# Restrict user access at component level within a stream

Tags: rtc

Is it possible to prevent users from delivering change sets to a component within a stream ?

For instance, an "`Integration`" stream should never see any deliver from the developers: only the **integration team** should be able to modify that "`Integration`" stream.

And yet, right now, any collaborator of the project area are able to make a repo workspace and, by changing its flow target (i.e. adding that "`Integration`" Stream and setting it "`current`"), are able to just deliver to that stream!?

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the restriction is rather about authorizing the deliver for anyone having a specific role, rather than restraining just one person by name.
So if that one person doesn't have a specific role associated with his/her profile in that Project Area, he/she won't be able to deliver on that stream.

You need to add a hook, through the "Operation Behavior" section, for the "deliver (server)" operation. See the illustration:

[image: hook for deliver]

The hook "Restrict Change set delivery to components in a stream" will allow only the users with the role "release_engineer" (custom role created just for our project) to deliver on the Stream mentioned in the field "Stream", for the components listed in the "Component / Permissions" array.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't seem to have person icon on Deliver(server), its just available on Deliver(client) ? I've added an image to original question to help explain this.

Comment: It seems im unable to upload images at the moment, im looking into this

Comment: @user470184 make sure to set that hook within the customized "Process Configuration" of a "Team Area", not on the "Project Area" itself (where I don't think said hook is available). That was also described as such at https://jazz.net/library/article/215#componentadvisor