# Are some options missing from my team area view?

Tags: rtc

When I open my 'Team Area' in rtc I just have 'Overview' & 'Links' tabs :

[image]

But reading accepted answer for this question : 
[Restrict user access at component level within a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518954/restrict-user-access-at-component-level-within-a-stream)

there are more options available for updating a team area ?

Does my rtc setup need to be configured so these options are viewable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to modify your RTC setup:
A Team area will by default **inherit** its process configuration from the parent area (team or project).

You need to click on the section "`Process: inherited`" (once unfolded, it reads "`Process Customization`").
You will see a link "Customize the process".

[image: Customize]

Clicking on it will git you access to the other tabs:

- Process Customization
- Process Customization Source

The Process Customization section on a Team Area with those tabs will look like:

[image: Customized]