# Rational Team Concert: Setting Operation Behavior only for one stream in a project area.

Tags: version-control, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

I've a scenario where there are several streams inside the Project and I have to restrict deliveries to a particular stream(just a maintenance stream,not an integration stream).

Precondition("Work Items must match a query" for ex) set in  Operations Behavior-> Source Control -> Deliver(Server) seem to be applicable for delivering into all the streams, but I want my preconditions to be considered only for one particular stream. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one Precondition which can be set for a given stream is "**`Restrict Change set delivery to components in a stream`**":

You can see it illustrated in "[Restrict user access at component level within a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518954/restrict-user-access-at-component-level-within-a-stream/10519357#10519357)".

However, this is a restriction based on the user's role, not the Work Item, so it might not be the kind of hook you are looking for.

Plus, this hook is defined within the customized "Process Configuration" of a "**`Team Area`**", not on the "Project Area" itself (where it doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks. I strongly believe this can be achieved in Clearcase. Considering that RTC is built on top of it I expected that it should be available and disappointed. Consider a scenario where a maintenance stream is created and in order to maintain the sanctity of the stream we want to impose some extra conditions(approvals etc). This used to be possible in Clearcase. Just wanted to know your thoughts as an expert in SCM areas.

Comment: @Varun yes, I see restriction mainly based on the team (in RTC3). May be it has been improved in RTC4 though.